# How to UPDATE and DELETE string items and entire dictionary items from a plist

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uinavigationcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

```
Root ---- Array
  Item 0- Dictionary
    fullName ---- String
    address ---- String
  Item 1 ---- Dictionary
    fullName ---- String
    address ---- String
```

I have the following plist structure.

Q1 How do I UPDATE/change fullName in code after it's already been saved in the plist file?

Q2 How do I DELETE just one Dictionary item say in the example above Item 0?

I am using the Navigation Controller TableView with the detail example.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for fixing my formatting.  I'm reading "Code and Preformatted Text" as we speak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really update or delete something form the plist file.  It's a bit more involved than that:

1. Read the plist file into memory
2. Alter the in-memory version
3. Write the new version back out to disk

Reading in a plist is pretty trivial.  In your case, since the root element is an array, you'd do:

```
NSMutableArray * plistContents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistFilePath];
```

Here we create a mutable array, since we know we're going to be changing stuff in it.  If we just wanted to read the information, we should use `NSArray` instead of `NSMutableArray`.

Altering the in-memory version is as simple as manipulating standard containers:

```
//delete the first dictionary:
[plistContents removeObjectAtIndex:0];

//Change a dictionary's full name:
NSMutableDictionary * firstDictionary = [[plistContents objectsAtIndex:0] mutableCopy];
[firstDictionary setObject:@"Mike" forKey:@"fullName"];
[plistContents replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:firstDictionary];
[firstDictionary release];
```

Here we have to make a mutable (changeable) copy of the dictionary, since reading in a plist only creates the immutable `NSDictionary`.  So we copy the dictionary, change the value we want to change, and then replace the original dictionary with our new modified dictionary.

Writing the plist out to disk is also simple:

```
//be sure you have write-permissions first!
[plistContents writeToFile:plistFilePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I will try this tomorrow it's 4am EST and I'm sure the kids will be waking me at 6.  Your information is very informative and well thought out.

Comment: I put [plistContents writeToFile:plistFilePath atomically:YES]; in my ViewDidDisappear and it works great.  Thanks.  Now I just have to get the update working.  The update happens on the details view, but with what you gave me I think I can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You don't operate on the data stored in a plist directly, you serialize objects to or unserialize objects from a plist. Since you want to alter the data, you need to unserialize to mutable objects. [`NSPropertyListSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPropertyListSerialization)'s [`propertyListWithData:options:format:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPropertyListSerialization/propertyListWithData%3aoptions%3aformat%3aerror%3a) will unserialize a plist creating mutable collections when you use the [`NSPropertyListMutableContainers`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSPropertyListMutableContainers) or [`NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves) option.

```
NSError *err=nil;
NSData *raw = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
id stuff = [NSPropertyListSerialization
                   propertyListWithData:raw
                                options:NSPropertyListMutableContainers 
                                 format:NULL
                                  error:&err;
      ];
if (err) {
    // couldn't parse the plist; handle the error.
    ...
    [err release];
}
[raw release];
```

This will get you a nested collection of `NSMutableArray`s, `NSMutableDictionary`s, either `NSString`s or `NSMutableString`s (depending on whether you specified `NSPropertyListMutableContainers` or `NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves`) &c. After you've unserialized the plist, use whatever method the collection provides to remove (e.g. `NSMutableArray`'s [`removeObjectAtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObjectAtIndex%3a), `NSMutableDictionary`'s [`removeObjectForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/removeObjectForKey%3a)) or set (e.g. [`replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/replaceObjectAtIndex%3awithObject%3a), [`setObject:forKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/setObject%3aforKey%3a)) items.

For more info, read the [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048-CJBGDEGD).

Comment: +1 for using the mutable containers option. I never remember that exists :)